# Putting a filter on a specific element inside an ID

Tags: html, css

When putting a filter on the image inside the ID I created both background and text get filtered, when my intention is just to lower the brightness of the background

I've tried making spererate classes and ID, but nothing worked the way I wanted it to.

HTML

```
<section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>I need to type something in here</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
#showcase{
  min-height: 400px;
  background:url('../img/writing-code33.jpg');
  filter: brightness(20%);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*#showcase background{
  filter: brightness(20%);
}*/

#showcase h1{
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I would take the `. container ` outside the `#showcase` and wrap both in a div - for example. Next I would position the `.container` absolute over the `#showcase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter on `#showcase` is applied to all its children. So you need to move the content outside of it. Try the following solution. This will also move the text to top and horizontally centered.

HTML

```
<section id="showcase"></section>
<div class="container">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p>I need to type something in here</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('../img/writing-code33.jpg');
  filter: brightness(20%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but the text is outside the #showcase area

Comment: With the given html and css, it's working fine on my side. It's possible that there are some other styles that may be causing the text to appear outside `#showcase`

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, I think I have it figured out now